# Plot over an image background in python

Tags: image, matplotlib, background

I would like to plot a graph over an image background using matplotlib. I found how to do it in matlab http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/plot_over_image_background

I've tried something basic like this:

```
im = plt.imread("dd.png")
implot = plt.imshow(im)
theta=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
z=np.cos(theta)*39+145
t=np.sin(theta)*39+535-78+39
plt.plot(z,t)
plt.show()
```

but it gave me something really ugly:

[image: something really ugly]

Comment: `imshow` can take a lot more arguments that allow you to specify where the image is placed and it's extent in coordinate-space. By default, the upper left corner is placed at (0, 0) and each pixel is 1x1 units in width and height.

Answer (score 172):

Just like in the MATLAB example that you linked to, you have to specify the desired extent of the image when you call in `imshow`.

By default, matplotlib and MATLAB both place the upper left corner of the image the origin, go down and to the right from there, and set each pixel as a 1x1 square in coordinate space. This is what your image is doing.

You can control this with the `extent` parameter which takes the form of a list `[left, right, bottom, top]`.

Not using extent looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread("airlines.jpg")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img)
```

[image]

You can see that we have a 1600 x 1200 of Samuel L. Jackson getting, quite frankly, rather annoyed with the snake aboard his airline flight.

But if we want to plot a line ranging from 0 to 300 in both dimension over this, we can do just that:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = range(300)
ax.imshow(img, extent=[0, 400, 0, 300])
ax.plot(x, x, '--', linewidth=5, color='firebrick')
```

[image]

I don't know if the line will help Mr. Jackson with his snake problem. At the very least, it won't make things any harder.