# how to implement image on wxpython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I want to use matplotlib's ***imread/imshow*** feature on wxpython.  What i want is not only image display but also plotting data on image. Is that possible on wxpython using WXAgg matplotlib?

I googled but couldn't find any example of it. Thanks  in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458251/plot-over-an-image-background-in-python

Comment: Thanks i solved my problem,  reading with PIL Image  library and plotting with canvas.draw().