# Matplotlib: How to add effects to background color of a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When making a subplot we use `facecolor` argument to set the color of the background. For example

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor="black")
ax.set_facecolor("black")
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

Now the above output is a plain black color. What I want is to add an effect to this plain black color so that it will look like this:

[image]

If you observe closely there is a bit of white color scattered over the black colored background. How to produce this effect in matplotlib?

Comment: Is this the background UtdArena is using? You are trying to recreate it?

Comment: Yes it is. Just I want to know how to add the effect. I have an idea around a light theme.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that only solid colours can be set. You could create the desired effect in a different program and save it as an image. Then, set the background of the plot to that image as in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34459284/13876078).